# What does the Sine of an array do in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array in Python created by the `np.linspace` function which returns an `i` amount of numbers evenly spaced out in a given range. In this case the range is 0 to 2.

```
import numpy as np
i = 10
t = np.linspace(2, i)
x = np.sin(t)
print(t)
print(x)
```

The output is 2 arrays. One for `t`, and one for `sin(t)`:

```
[0.         0.22222222 0.44444444 0.66666667 0.88888889 1.11111111
 1.33333333 1.55555556 1.77777778 2.        ] 
[0.         0.22039774 0.42995636 0.6183698  0.77637192 0.8961922
 0.9719379  0.99988386 0.9786557  0.90929743]
```

The `t` array increases by `0.22222222` every time. I initially thought that the `x` array would be the `sin` of each index in the `t` array. So for example, `x[2] = sin(t[2]) = 7.757e-3`. But this is clearly not the case.

So what does the Sine of an array do in Python?

Comment: `t` is radians, not degrees.  That's pretty standard for programing languages

Answer (score 1):

**numpy.sin()**  helps to calculate trignmetric sine for all elements in x.
note:- All the elements in x should be in radian

```
import numpy as np
i = 10
t = np.radians(np.linspace(2, i))
x = np.sin(t)
print(t)
print(x)
```